# .NET like DataTable implementation in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a scenario where I have to run a query which will give number of messages for a partucular id. If that id contains any unread messages I want to show them one by one in alert boxes. So fro that I have so far created a storede procedure which I am executing through TQuery called MembershipMessagesQuery (I HAVE TO USE BDE :() then this TQuery is bind to TDataSource (dsUnreadDataSource). 
Now I want to display the alert boxes using "show message " But I will iterate through the record set. as in .NET we have datatable which can be filled with sqldataadapter but here what to do? Please help.

```
MembershipMessagesQuery.ParamByName('membershipnumber').AsString  :=custQuery.FieldByName('cust_code').AsString;
MembershipMessagesQuery.ParamByName('primarymemberflag').AsString  := 'a';
MembershipMessagesQuery.Open;
```

How can I iterate through each record and siplay the message column in the show message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very good articles and valuable resources http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Navigating_Datasets and  http://delphi.about.com/od/database/ss/dbcourse_browse.htm

a possible solution: (code was not tested, it is only to give you a hint on how to solve your issue)

```
MembershipMessagesQuery.First;
while not MembershipMessagesQuery.eof do 
 begin
  Showmessage(MembershipMessagesQuery.FieldByName(yourfieldname).AsString);
  MembershipMessagesQuery.Next;
 end;
```

another good example
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/RecordCount_%28Delphi%29